# Map Terrain Analysis: Alternative to numpy.roll function?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to analyse map terrain given by the [StarCraft 2 bot API](https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2).

A beginner's task for this analysis was finding cliffs for reapers, which are special units in SC2 that can jump up and down cliffs.

To solve this, I analyse points where the point itself is not pathable (=cliff) and the northern and southern two points are pathable. Pathable points are marked as 1 and not pathable as 0 in the array.

The terrain map exists as a 2D numpy array. The following is a small excerpt from a larger 200x200 array:

```
import numpy as np
example = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here, the points [2, 1] and [2, 2] would match the criteria where the points themselves are not pathable (=0) and the points above and below them are pathable (=1).

This can be achieved by the following code:

```
above = np.roll(example, 1, axis=0) # Shift rows downwards
below = np.roll(example, -1, axis=0) # Shift rows upwards
result = np.zeros_like(example) # Create array with zeros
result[(example == 0) & (above == 1) & (below == 1)] = 1 # Set cells to 1 that match condition
print(repr(result))
#   array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Now my question is if the same can be achieved with less code?**

The np.roll function creates a new np.array object each time, so analysing hundreds of nearby points could probably result in 100 lines of uncessary code and high memory usage.

I'm trying to find something similar to

```
result = np.zeros_like(example)
result[(example == 0) & (example[-1, 0] == 1) & (example[1, 0 == 1)] = 1
# or
result[(example == 0) & ((example[-1:2, 0].sum() == 2)] = 1
```

Here the numbers in the brackets display the relative position to the currently analysed point, but I don't know if there is a way to get this to work with numpy.

Also the result for the zeroth row wouldn't be clear when checking the point "above" it: It could access either the last row, result in an error or return a default value (0 or 1).

**Edit:**
I found [this post](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Neighbours-in-an-array) and it pointed me towards the [scipy convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) function which can be applied here, which might be what I am looking for:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
example = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0]])
kernel = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)
kernel[::2, 1] = 1
print(repr(kernel))
# array([[0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0]])
result2 = signal.convolve2d(example, kernel, mode="same")
print(repr(result2))
# array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 2, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0]])
result2[result2 < 2] = 0
result2[result2 == 2] = 1
print(repr(result2))
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Edit2:**
Another solution may be [scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter.html) which seems to work similarly:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
example = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0]])
kernel = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)
kernel[::2, 1] = 1
print(repr(kernel))
# array([[0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0]])
result3 = ndimage.minimum_filter(example, footprint=kernel_vertical, mode="constant")
print(repr(result3))
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Have you looked at using the numpy `ix_` function to extract a sub-array to test against your cliff criteria?  Not sure if it would result in less code, but it would certainly use less memory.

Comment: I have now, thanks! However, I am unsure how to apply this here if I want to extract information relative to other cells. It should be useful if I am going to use two for loops to loop through all the cells in the array.